# Getting started with Google Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am having really difficult time trying to connect Google Storage. All I need is to be able to upload PDF file to a bucket that I've created on Google Storage Console. The documentation seems to be all over the place and lacking simple examples of PHP code. So here's what I've done so far:

Installed cloud storage

```
$ composer require google/cloud-storage
```

Added billing as per Google's requirement. Enabled Cloud Storage API. Created project and added a bucket.

Attempted to use the following example:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

define("PROJECT_ID", "my-project");
define("BUCKET_NAME", "my-bucket");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("API_Cloud_Storage");
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->setScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]);

$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

$request = $service->buckets->listBuckets(PROJECT_ID);

foreach ($request["items"] as $bucket)
    printf("%s\n", $bucket->getName());
```

Keep on getting error on

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in /home/domain/public_html/test.php:11 ...
```

I know the vendor/autoload.php file is loading because I have no issues with AWS in a different script.
I didn't even pass the first line. What am I missing?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I think you're using a tutorial focused around an older version of the SDK. Check out the readme for the `google/cloud-storage` package at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage - you should be instantiating a `Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient`.

Comment: Hmm, good point about older version -- quite possible. It's from 2017. Also I've installed the entire Cloud package. $ composer require google/cloud

Answer (score 0):

You have [the documentation page for Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-php) with a PHP sample and detailed instructions. There's also a link to [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage) for that quickstart, in addition to the one shared by ceejayoz in the comments.